# How do I subtract these 2 list in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have 2 lists

```
list1=( "Arwen Hagan" "Catriona Hutton" "Sasha Tucker" "Virgil Mcdowell" )
list2=( "Arwen Hagan" "Catriona Hutton" )
```

I want `list1 - list2` to return a new list like this:

```
final=( "Sasha Tucker" "Virgil Mcdowell" )
```

**My attempt**

```
final=($(comm -3 <(printf "%s\n" "${list1[@]}" | sort) <(printf "%s\n" "${list2[@]}" | sort) | sort -n))
```

```
for val in "${listr[@]}"; do
  echo $val
done
```

**Output**

```
Sasha
Tucker
Virgil
Mcdowell
```

**Expected Output**

```
Sasha Tucker
Virgil Mcdowell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this single line `mapfile + grep + printf` solution:

```sh
mapfile -t final < <(grep -vxFf <(printf '%s\n' "${list2[@]}") <(printf '%s\n' "${list1[@]}"))

# check resulting array
declare -p final
declare -a final=([0]="Sasha Tucker" [1]="Virgil Mcdowell")
```

Here:

- `printf '%s\n' "${list2[@]}"` prints each item in array on new line
- `<(printf '%s\n' "${list2[@]}")` is process substitution to treat output of `printf` like a file
- `grep -vxFf file2 file1` will find entries in `file1` that are not present in `file2`. Options used are: `x - exact match`, `v - inverse match`, `F - fixed string search` and `f - use file for input pattern`